# In Jmeter vars vs props for while controller

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Before test, I added x variables to TestPlans,
After I run test as 10 thread 10 seconds ramp up
In while controller for condition that

```
${__javaScript("${x}" != "",)}
```

In beanshell:

```
vars.put("x","");
```

Normally, each thread occured 1 second, First thread changed x variable as "", therefore another threads don't meet if condition. why do threads get looped though ?

Note: Other threads did not start testing when using property instead of variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [JMeter documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> Properties are not the same as variables. **Variables are local to a thread**; properties are common to all threads

so when you do `vars.put("x","");` you change `x` variable value **only for the current thread**, other threads have their own values of the `x` variable.

If you want to amend the value so it would be visible for all threads - you will have to:

1. Change `vars.put("x","");` to `props.put("x","");`
2. In the While Controller `${__javaScript("${__P(x,)}" != "",)}`

Also: since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so it worth considering migrating (the same applies to __javaScript() function in the While Controller), more information: [Beanshell vs. JSR223 vs. Java For JMeter: Complete Showdown](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter)